# Restricting SSH sessions for accounts on ubuntu server

Tags: server

May someone please show me how I would restrict accounts/people logging into an ubuntu 10.04 server by SSH to a single active session at a time for each account that logs into the server.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `man sshd_config`, you can see that there is an option for `MaxSessions`.  Unfortunately, this is the maximum number of sessions per network connection, not the maximum number for a specific user.

One thing you can do is set `UsePAM yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, then configure PAM to handle the user limits by enabling the PAM module `pam_limits.so`.  If you only want the limits to apply to ssh sessions, add the following line to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

I'm pretty sure all of the above stuff is the default configuration, now comes the part that actually sets the limit.  `pam_limits.so` pulls its limits from `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  If you want a user to only be able to have one active session at a time, just add the following line to that file:

```
user    hard    maxlogins    1
```

Once this is set up, on any log in attempt when there's already an active session, the user will get the error `Too many logins for 'user'.`  To make this apply to all users, use `*` for the user.  You can also have it apply to certain groups, for instance, use `@users` to apply to rule to everyone in the `users` group.

Comment: Any results?  Did this do what you wanted?

Comment: how do. No it did not achieve what i wanted. even after making the changes i could still open multiple sessions for the same user at the same time

Comment: Odd, it worked for me when I tested it.  Can you paste the line you added to limits.conf?

Comment: You are angel Kevin..there was a syntax error on my limits.conf line..it works..Thank you

Comment: The answer provided by KevinC is  correct.